# (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] Unexpected Error

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm getting below error when I try to deploy an Spring Boot app to google cloud.

```
(gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] Unexpected Error.
```

I'm using com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-plugin version 1.3.1, goal deploy. This error message is not useful at all! I appreciate any help with this as I am not much familiar with Google Cloud. Where should I start looking?

```
[INFO] GCLOUD: d4498962e4fc: Pushed
[INFO] GCLOUD: latest: digest: sha256:1c2516746601c4fe68dac3507fe684380b122ebc1801e8dc234599825d3cfb89 size: 2416 
[INFO] GCLOUD: DONE 
[INFO] GCLOUD: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] GCLOUD:
[INFO] GCLOUD: Updating service [default]...
[INFO] GCLOUD: .....................failed.
[INFO] GCLOUD: ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] Unexpected Error. ()
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO]------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Can you check if the service is actually working?

Comment: Under App Engine > Services I only see default but when I click on that link (opens a new tab), I see "Error: Server Error The server encountered an error and could not complete your request. Please try again in 30 seconds.". So service is NOT working.

Comment: Is there a proper documentation on how to deploy an existing Spring Boot app to Google Cloud (App Engine)? I feel like there's a problem with app engine, yet there's no command to delete it??? Also projects can not be deleted immediately??? I followed this https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-app-engine-springboot/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0 and run into the problem in this ticket

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out, same problem encountered by others.

- [(gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] Unexpected Error. ()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46070679/gcloud-app-deploy-error-response-13-unexpected-error)
- https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-java/issues/281#issuecomment-327572081

Result of [this ticket](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-java/issues/281#issuecomment-327572081) must bring a resolution.

Comment: A workaround has been posted at the above github issue page.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue. My problem was my cloudbuild.yaml was trying to deploy the app, which I intended to call via a Cloud Built Trigger. Only problem was it was in the root dir, which "gcloud app deploy" also tries to use when you deploy. The app would try to recursively deploy over and over causing the error.

**Solution**: move cloudbuild.yaml into a different directory, and configure the build trigger to point to that path, (instead of just looking for it in the root dir, wihch is the default behavior) which they make really easy to do in the gcloud console.

Answer (score -1):

Simply rename your main python file (maybe it is app.py) to main.py
In the resources section of yaml file increase the number of cpu and the assigning memory if you are with the flex plan.