# (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] Unexpected Error. ()

Tags: java, google-app-engine, app-engine-flexible

I'm unable to deploy with the App Engine (Java Flexible) and receive only the information in the header, which is not very informative.
I've tried to deploy the helloworld-servlet sample app (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-java/tree/master/helloworld-servlet) using the tutorial just to really keep it simple but I still get the same fault.

Here is the laterm, failing, part of the log (with http-logging turned on):

```
    [INFO] GCLOUD: -- headers start --
    [INFO] GCLOUD: -content-encoding: gzip
    [INFO] GCLOUD: alt-svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="39,38,37,35"
    [INFO] GCLOUD: cache-control: private
    [INFO] GCLOUD: content-length: 588
    [INFO] GCLOUD: content-location: https://appengine.googleapis.com/v1/apps/ticksterimportexport/operations/921b89d2-7eaa-41a1-87d2-c4be496793a0?alt=json
   [INFO] GCLOUD: content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
   [INFO] GCLOUD: date: Wed, 06 Sep 2017 05:46:41 GMT
   [INFO] GCLOUD: server: ESF
   [INFO] GCLOUD: status: 200
   [INFO] GCLOUD: transfer-encoding: chunked
   [INFO] GCLOUD: vary: Origin, X-Origin, Referer
   [INFO] GCLOUD: x-content-type-options: nosniff
   [INFO] GCLOUD: x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
   [INFO] GCLOUD: x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
   [INFO] GCLOUD: -- headers end --
   [INFO] GCLOUD: -- body start --
   [INFO] GCLOUD: {
   [INFO] GCLOUD:   "name": "apps/ticksterimportexport/operations/921b89d2-7eaa-41a1-87d2-c4be496793a0",
   [INFO] GCLOUD:   "metadata": {
   [INFO] GCLOUD:     "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.appengine.v1.OperationMetadataV1",
   [INFO] GCLOUD:     "method": "google.appengine.v1.Versions.CreateVersion",
   [INFO] GCLOUD:     "insertTime": "2017-09-06T05:46:06.731Z",
   [INFO] GCLOUD:     "user": "produktion@atg.se",
   [INFO] GCLOUD:     "target": "apps/ticksterimportexport/services/default/versions/20170906t064538",
   [INFO] GCLOUD:     "ephemeralMessage": "Deployment failed. Attempting to cleanup deployment artifacts."
   [INFO] GCLOUD:   },
   [INFO] GCLOUD:   "done": true,
   [INFO] GCLOUD:   "error": {
   [INFO] GCLOUD:     "code": 13,
   [INFO] GCLOUD:     "message": "Unexpected Error. ()"
   [INFO] GCLOUD:   }
   [INFO] GCLOUD: }
   [INFO] GCLOUD:
   [INFO] GCLOUD: -- body end --
   [INFO] GCLOUD: total round trip time (request+response): 0.177 secs
   [INFO] GCLOUD: ---- response end ----
   [INFO] GCLOUD: ----------------------
   [INFO] GCLOUD: failed.
   [INFO] GCLOUD: ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] Unexpected Error. ()
```

Seems like everything is going well until the point of service startup.
If I look in my Control Panel under Container Registry I can see my container images but there are no deployed instances of the service and it is unreachable.

This is the link to my app:
https://hello-world-project-179013.appspot.com

I would be very grateful for any input on this matter.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Code 13 is usually a permission problem

Comment: Do you mean that I am lacking permissions to start the service even though I can still upload to the container?
Where can I manage such permission?

Comment: Sorry I do not really know, but maybe a log file is the wrong permission?

Comment: I really don't understand what you mean by log-file?
I'm not getting any logs at all since the application doesn't start, since it won't deploy.
In fact I can't even find a log anywhere in the console that says that the deploy failed. I see that fault only in my command line.

Comment: I think I'm running into similar issue, please check my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46059583/gcloud-app-deploy-error-response-13-unexpected-error?noredirect=1#comment79082619_46059583

Comment: Yeah!
Les Vogel is looking into the issue in this thread: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-java/issues/281#issuecomment-327572081

Comment: There is now a suggested workaround  posted on the GitHub issue which has been shown to fix the issue for some projects: In order to workaround this issue, please set use_deprecated_preparation using the following command:

"$ gcloud config set app/use_deprecated_preparation True"

Once the above property is set, please retry deployment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [(gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: \[13\] Unexpected Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46059583/gcloud-app-deploy-error-response-13-unexpected-error)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47515970/3615567