# Error Response: [13] An internal error occurred while creating a Google Cloud Storage bucket

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to push a `Nodejs` sample app `Hello World` but after pushing I am getting error.

> ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] An internal error
>   occurred while creating a Google Cloud Storage bucket.

[image: IAM Admin Console]

[image: Service Accounts]

There is nothing wrong with the code as it is just a sample app downloaded from google.

I have seen other SO posts related to this error but none of them helped.

Can anyone please tell me a Fix for this error.[image: My IAM]

I also tried to run command in `debug` using command and got following output.

```
gcloud app deploy app.yaml --verbosity debug

DEBUG: No bucket specified, retrieving default bucket.
    DEBUG: Using bucket [gs://staging.united-backbone-186810.appspot.com].
    DEBUG: Service [appengineflex.googleapis.com] is already enabled for project [united-backbone-186810]
    Beginning deployment of service [default]...
    INFO: Need Dockerfile to be generated for runtime nodejs
    Building and pushing image for service [default]
    INFO: Uploading [c:\users\sudha\appdata\local\temp\tmpaj1p9z\src.tgz] to [asia.gcr.io/united-backbone-186810/appengine/default.20171122t164838:latest]
    DEBUG: Using runtime builder root [gs://runtime-builders/]
    DEBUG: Loading runtimes manifest from [gs://runtime-builders/runtimes.yaml]
    INFO: Reading [<googlecloudsdk.api_lib.storage.storage_util.ObjectReference object at 0x0000000006631400>]
    DEBUG: Resolved runtime [nodejs] as build configuration [gs://runtime-builders/nodejs-default-builder-20171116155610.yaml]
    INFO: Using runtime builder [gs://runtime-builders/nodejs-default-builder-20171116155610.yaml]
    INFO: Reading [<googlecloudsdk.api_lib.storage.storage_util.ObjectReference object at 0x0000000006642390>]
    Started cloud build [c3702b4b-7bc8-4861-944f-8490bf183078].
    DEBUG: GCS logfile url is https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/staging.united-backbone-186810.appspot.com/o/log-c3702b4b-7bc8-4861-944f-8490bf183078.txt?alt=media
    To see logs in the Cloud Console: https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr/builds/c3702b4b-7bc8-4861-944f-8490bf183078?project=united-backbone-186810
    DEBUG: Operation [operations/build/united-backbone-186810/YzM3MDJiNGItN2JjOC00ODYxLTk0NGYtODQ5MGJmMTgzMDc4] not complete. Waiting 1s.
    DEBUG: Reading GCS logfile: 416 (no new content; keep polling)
    DEBUG: Operation [operations/build/united-backbone-186810/YzM3MDJiNGItN2JjOC00ODYxLTk0NGYtODQ5MGJmMTgzMDc4] not complete. Waiting 1s.
    DEBUG: Reading GCS logfile: 206 (read 233 bytes)
    ------------------------------------------------- REMOTE BUILD OUTPUT --------------------------------------------------
    starting build "c3702b4b-7bc8-4861-944f-8490bf183078"

    FETCHSOURCE
    Fetching storage object: gs://staging.united-backbone-186810.appspot.com/asia.gcr.io/united-backbone-186810/appengine/default.20171122t164838:latest#1511349522754483
    DEBUG: Operation [operations/build/united-backbone-186810/YzM3MDJiNGItN2JjOC00ODYxLTk0NGYtODQ5MGJmMTgzMDc4] not complete. Waiting 1s.
    DEBUG: Reading GCS logfile: 416 (no new content; keep polling)
    DEBUG: Operation [operations/build/united-backbone-186810/YzM3MDJiNGItN2JjOC00ODYxLTk0NGYtODQ5MGJmMTgzMDc4] not complete. Waiting 1s.
    DEBUG: Reading GCS logfile: 206 (read 398 bytes)
    Copying gs://staging.united-backbone-186810.appspot.com/asia.gcr.io/united-backbone-186810/appengine/default.20171122t164838:latest#1511349522754483...
    - [1 files][  1.8 KiB/  1.8 KiB]
    DEBUG: Operation [operations/build/united-backbone-186810/YzM3MDJiNGItN2JjOC00ODYxLTk0NGYtODQ5MGJmMTgzMDc4] not complete. Waiting 1s.
    DEBUG: Reading GCS logfile: 206 (read 2198 bytes)
    Operation completed over 1 objects/1.8 KiB.
    BUILD
    Step #0: Pulling image: gcr.io/gcp-runtimes/nodejs/gen-dockerfile@sha256:196bc20ff8d91905dc071100399538814e2c619d0d27576c35a6405674da696c
    Step #0: sha256:196bc20ff8d91905dc071100399538814e2c619d0d27576c35a6405674da696c: Pulling from gcp-runtimes/nodejs/gen-dockerfile
    Step #0: Digest: sha256:196bc20ff8d91905dc071100399538814e2c619d0d27576c35a6405674da696c
    Step #0: Status: Downloaded newer image for gcr.io/gcp-runtimes/nodejs/gen-dockerfile@sha256:196bc20ff8d91905dc071100399538814e2c619d0d27576c35a6405674da696c
    Starting Step #0
    Step #0: Checking for Node.js.
    Finished Step #0
    Step #1: Pulling image: gcr.io/cloud_builders/docker@sha256:8f8f572201e2b2ae876d8ca8b05c7d44df994e7ea8352c334ee5bae7ca3dc7f9
    Step #1: sha256:8f8f572201e2b2ae876d8ca8b05c7d44df994e7ea8352c334ee5bae7ca3dc7f9: Pulling from cloud_builders/docker
    Step #1: Digest: sha256:8f8f572201e2b2ae876d8ca8b05c7d44df994e7ea8352c334ee5bae7ca3dc7f9
    Step #1: Status: Downloaded newer image for gcr.io/cloud_builders/docker@sha256:8f8f572201e2b2ae876d8ca8b05c7d44df994e7ea8352c334ee5bae7ca3dc7f9
    Starting Step #1
    Step #1: Sending build context to Docker daemon  11.26kB
    Step #1: Step 1/5 : FROM gcr.io/google-appengine/nodejs@sha256:2c743f7509798cca81aaebaa339c899c4d1924153beb4a94df00ff6af238fcb2
    Step #1: sha256:2c743f7509798cca81aaebaa339c899c4d1924153beb4a94df00ff6af238fcb2: Pulling from google-appengine/nodejs
    Step #1: Digest: sha256:2c743f7509798cca81aaebaa339c899c4d1924153beb4a94df00ff6af238fcb2
    Step #1: Status: Downloaded newer image for gcr.io/google-appengine/nodejs@sha256:2c743f7509798cca81aaebaa339c899c4d1924153beb4a94df00ff6af238fcb2
    Step #1:  ---> 669f53c480d3
    Step #1: Step 2/5 : COPY . /app/
    Step #1:  ---> 388693438f26
    Step #1: Removing intermediate container 45b4eecdfef0
    Step #1: Step 3/5 : RUN /usr/local/bin/install_node '>=4.3.2'
    Step #1:  ---> Running in 67ea703659bc
    Step #1:  ---> 7b5b6d0283c5
    Step #1: Removing intermediate container 67ea703659bc
    Step #1: Step 4/5 : RUN npm install --unsafe-perm ||   ((if [ -f npm-debug.log ]; then       cat npm-debug.log;     fi) && false)
    Step #1:  ---> Running in 2d7b75885d6c
    DEBUG: Operation [operations/build/united-backbone-186810/YzM3MDJiNGItN2JjOC00ODYxLTk0NGYtODQ5MGJmMTgzMDc4] not complete. Waiting 1s.
    DEBUG: Reading GCS logfile: 206 (read 145 bytes)
    Step #1: [91mnpm[0m[91m notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
    Step #1: [0madded 43 packages in 1.695s
    DEBUG: Operation [operations/build/united-backbone-186810/YzM3MDJiNGItN2JjOC00ODYxLTk0NGYtODQ5MGJmMTgzMDc4] not complete. Waiting 1s.
    DEBUG: Reading GCS logfile: 206 (read 1222 bytes)
    Step #1:  ---> e802843c73cd
    Step #1: Removing intermediate container 2d7b75885d6c
    Step #1: Step 5/5 : CMD npm start
    Step #1:  ---> Running in cef15318568d
    Step #1:  ---> b61594a5ec64
    Step #1: Removing intermediate container cef15318568d
    Step #1: Successfully built b61594a5ec64
    Step #1: Successfully tagged asia.gcr.io/united-backbone-186810/appengine/default.20171122t164838:latest
    Finished Step #1
    PUSH
    Pushing asia.gcr.io/united-backbone-186810/appengine/default.20171122t164838:latest
    The push refers to a repository [asia.gcr.io/united-backbone-186810/appengine/default.20171122t164838]
    737512f7e42b: Preparing
    ec3a6c686d39: Preparing
    644f071ca81b: Preparing
    226846715c53: Preparing
    e0a3cc0c6e70: Preparing
    c2003e396592: Preparing
    8fc48a7a910e: Preparing
    9aa804bf0e6a: Preparing
    749e521e9c3d: Preparing
    31cb62ec9f95: Preparing
    c2003e396592: Waiting
    8fc48a7a910e: Waiting
    9aa804bf0e6a: Waiting
    749e521e9c3d: Waiting
    31cb62ec9f95: Waiting
    226846715c53: Layer already exists
    e0a3cc0c6e70: Layer already exists
    644f071ca81b: Layer already exists
    8fc48a7a910e: Layer already exists
    c2003e396592: Layer already exists
    31cb62ec9f95: Layer already exists
    749e521e9c3d: Layer already exists
    9aa804bf0e6a: Layer already exists
    DEBUG: Operation [operations/build/united-backbone-186810/YzM3MDJiNGItN2JjOC00ODYxLTk0NGYtODQ5MGJmMTgzMDc4] not complete. Waiting 1s.
    DEBUG: Reading GCS logfile: 206 (read 21 bytes)
    ec3a6c686d39: Pushed
    DEBUG: Operation [operations/build/united-backbone-186810/YzM3MDJiNGItN2JjOC00ODYxLTk0NGYtODQ5MGJmMTgzMDc4] not complete. Waiting 1s.
    DEBUG: Reading GCS logfile: 206 (read 21 bytes)
    737512f7e42b: Pushed
    DEBUG: Operation [operations/build/united-backbone-186810/YzM3MDJiNGItN2JjOC00ODYxLTk0NGYtODQ5MGJmMTgzMDc4] not complete. Waiting 1s.
    DEBUG: Reading GCS logfile: 206 (read 104 bytes)
    latest: digest: sha256:6659b586325b131087fcbf872abf618fa1ee45503fff47cad7bb9e92d63bcd12 size: 2413
    DONE
    DEBUG: Operation [operations/build/united-backbone-186810/YzM3MDJiNGItN2JjOC00ODYxLTk0NGYtODQ5MGJmMTgzMDc4] complete. Result: {
        "response": {
            "finishTime": "2017-11-22T11:19:11.119096Z",
            "status": "SUCCESS",
            "timeout": "600s",
            "startTime": "2017-11-22T11:18:45.353017219Z",
            "logsBucket": "staging.united-backbone-186810.appspot.com",
            "results": {
                "images": [
                    {
                        "name": "asia.gcr.io/united-backbone-186810/appengine/default.20171122t164838",
                        "digest": "sha256:6659b586325b131087fcbf872abf618fa1ee45503fff47cad7bb9e92d63bcd12"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "asia.gcr.io/united-backbone-186810/appengine/default.20171122t164838:latest",
                        "digest": "sha256:6659b586325b131087fcbf872abf618fa1ee45503fff47cad7bb9e92d63bcd12"
                    }
                ],
                "buildStepImages": [
                    "",
                    ""
                ]
            },
            "createTime": "2017-11-22T11:18:44.769257383Z",
            "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.devtools.cloudbuild.v1.Build",
            "source": {
                "storageSource": {
                    "object": "asia.gcr.io/united-backbone-186810/appengine/default.20171122t164838:latest",
                    "bucket": "staging.united-backbone-186810.appspot.com"
                }
            },
            "options": {
                "substitutionOption": "ALLOW_LOOSE"
            },
            "steps": [
                {
                    "args": [
                        "--runtime-image",
                        "gcr.io/google-appengine/nodejs@sha256:2c743f7509798cca81aaebaa339c899c4d1924153beb4a94df00ff6af238fcb2"
                    ],
                    "name": "gcr.io/gcp-runtimes/nodejs/gen-dockerfile@sha256:196bc20ff8d91905dc071100399538814e2c619d0d27576c35a6405674da696c",
                    "env": [
                        "GAE_APPLICATION_YAML_PATH=app.yaml"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "args": [
                        "build",
                        "-t",
                        "asia.gcr.io/united-backbone-186810/appengine/default.20171122t164838:latest",
                        "."
                    ],
                    "name": "gcr.io/cloud_builders/docker@sha256:8f8f572201e2b2ae876d8ca8b05c7d44df994e7ea8352c334ee5bae7ca3dc7f9",
                    "env": [
                        "GAE_APPLICATION_YAML_PATH=app.yaml"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "sourceProvenance": {
                "resolvedStorageSource": {
                    "generation": "1511349522754483",
                    "object": "asia.gcr.io/united-backbone-186810/appengine/default.20171122t164838:latest",
                    "bucket": "staging.united-backbone-186810.appspot.com"
                },
                "fileHashes": {
                    "gs://staging.united-backbone-186810.appspot.com/asia.gcr.io/united-backbone-186810/appengine/default.20171122t164838:latest#1511349522754483": {
                        "fileHash": [
                            {
                                "type": "MD5",
                                "value": "RCwNC0JHUlmvZZz+C5RYsw=="
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
            "projectId": "united-backbone-186810",
            "images": [
                "asia.gcr.io/united-backbone-186810/appengine/default.20171122t164838:latest"
            ],
            "substitutions": {
                "_GAE_APPLICATION_YAML_PATH": "app.yaml",
                "_OUTPUT_IMAGE": "asia.gcr.io/united-backbone-186810/appengine/default.20171122t164838:latest"
            },
            "id": "c3702b4b-7bc8-4861-944f-8490bf183078",
            "logUrl": "https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr/builds/c3702b4b-7bc8-4861-944f-8490bf183078?project=united-backbone-186810"
        },
        "done": true,
        "name": "operations/build/united-backbone-186810/YzM3MDJiNGItN2JjOC00ODYxLTk0NGYtODQ5MGJmMTgzMDc4",
        "metadata": {
            "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.devtools.cloudbuild.v1.BuildOperationMetadata",
            "build": {
                "finishTime": "2017-11-22T11:19:11.119096Z",
                "status": "SUCCESS",
                "timeout": "600s",
                "startTime": "2017-11-22T11:18:45.353017219Z",
                "logsBucket": "staging.united-backbone-186810.appspot.com",
                "results": {
                    "images": [
                        {
                            "name": "asia.gcr.io/united-backbone-186810/appengine/default.20171122t164838",
                            "digest": "sha256:6659b586325b131087fcbf872abf618fa1ee45503fff47cad7bb9e92d63bcd12"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "asia.gcr.io/united-backbone-186810/appengine/default.20171122t164838:latest",
                            "digest": "sha256:6659b586325b131087fcbf872abf618fa1ee45503fff47cad7bb9e92d63bcd12"
                        }
                    ],
                    "buildStepImages": [
                        "",
                        ""
                    ]
                },
                "id": "c3702b4b-7bc8-4861-944f-8490bf183078",
                "source": {
                    "storageSource": {
                        "object": "asia.gcr.io/united-backbone-186810/appengine/default.20171122t164838:latest",
                        "bucket": "staging.united-backbone-186810.appspot.com"
                    }
                },
                "options": {
                    "substitutionOption": "ALLOW_LOOSE"
                },
                "steps": [
                    {
                        "args": [
                            "--runtime-image",
                            "gcr.io/google-appengine/nodejs@sha256:2c743f7509798cca81aaebaa339c899c4d1924153beb4a94df00ff6af238fcb2"
                        ],
                        "name": "gcr.io/gcp-runtimes/nodejs/gen-dockerfile@sha256:196bc20ff8d91905dc071100399538814e2c619d0d27576c35a6405674da696c",
                        "env": [
                            "GAE_APPLICATION_YAML_PATH=app.yaml"
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "args": [
                            "build",
                            "-t",
                            "asia.gcr.io/united-backbone-186810/appengine/default.20171122t164838:latest",
                            "."
                        ],
                        "name": "gcr.io/cloud_builders/docker@sha256:8f8f572201e2b2ae876d8ca8b05c7d44df994e7ea8352c334ee5bae7ca3dc7f9",
                        "env": [
                            "GAE_APPLICATION_YAML_PATH=app.yaml"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "sourceProvenance": {
                    "resolvedStorageSource": {
                        "generation": "1511349522754483",
                        "object": "asia.gcr.io/united-backbone-186810/appengine/default.20171122t164838:latest",
                        "bucket": "staging.united-backbone-186810.appspot.com"
                    },
                    "fileHashes": {
                        "gs://staging.united-backbone-186810.appspot.com/asia.gcr.io/united-backbone-186810/appengine/default.20171122t164838:latest#1511349522754483": {
                            "fileHash": [
                                {
                                    "type": "MD5",
                                    "value": "RCwNC0JHUlmvZZz+C5RYsw=="
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
                "projectId": "united-backbone-186810",
                "images": [
                    "asia.gcr.io/united-backbone-186810/appengine/default.20171122t164838:latest"
                ],
                "substitutions": {
                    "_GAE_APPLICATION_YAML_PATH": "app.yaml",
                    "_OUTPUT_IMAGE": "asia.gcr.io/united-backbone-186810/appengine/default.20171122t164838:latest"
                },
                "createTime": "2017-11-22T11:18:44.769257383Z",
                "logUrl": "https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr/builds/c3702b4b-7bc8-4861-944f-8490bf183078?project=united-backbone-186810"
            }
        }
    }
    DEBUG: Reading GCS logfile: 416 (no new content; keep polling)
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    DEBUG: Converted YAML to JSON: "{
      "betaSettings": {
        "module_yaml_path": "app.yaml",
        "vm_runtime": "nodejs"
      },
      "env": "flex",
      "handlers": [
        {
          "script": {
            "scriptPath": "PLACEHOLDER"
          },
          "urlRegex": ".*"
        }
      ],
      "runtime": "vm"
    }"
    DEBUG: Received operation: [apps/united-backbone-186810/operations/51892505-4cb2-4b11-8431-ee7b62f0f236]
    DEBUG: Operation [apps/united-backbone-186810/operations/51892505-4cb2-4b11-8431-ee7b62f0f236] not complete. Waiting to retry.
    Updating service [default] (this may take several minutes).../DEBUG: Operation [apps/united-backbone-186810/operations/51892505-4cb2-4b11-8431-ee7b62f0f236] not complete. Waiting to retry.
    Updating service [default] (this may take several minutes)...\DEBUG: Operation [apps/united-backbone-186810/operations/51892505-4cb2-4b11-8431-ee7b62f0f236] complete. Result: {
        "metadata": {
            "target": "apps/united-backbone-186810/services/default/versions/20171122t164838",
            "method": "google.appengine.v1.Versions.CreateVersion",
            "user": "prafactor9@gmail.com",
            "insertTime": "2017-11-22T11:19:14.120Z",
            "ephemeralMessage": "Deployment failed. Attempting to cleanup deployment artifacts.",
            "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.appengine.v1.OperationMetadataV1"
        },
        "done": true,
        "name": "apps/united-backbone-186810/operations/51892505-4cb2-4b11-8431-ee7b62f0f236",
        "error": {
            "message": "An internal error occurred while creating a Google Cloud Storage bucket.",
            "code": 13
        }
    }
    Updating service [default] (this may take several minutes)...failed.
    DEBUG: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] An internal error occurred while creating a Google Cloud Storage bucket.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\sudha\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\calliope\cli.py", line 789, in Execute
        resources = calliope_command.Run(cli=self, args=args)
      File "C:\Users\sudha\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\calliope\backend.py", line 756, in Run
        resources = command_instance.Run(args)
      File "C:\Users\sudha\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\surface\app\deploy.py", line 65, in Run
        parallel_build=False)
      File "C:\Users\sudha\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\command_lib\app\deploy_util.py", line 587, in RunDeploy
        flex_image_build_option=flex_image_build_option)
      File "C:\Users\sudha\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\command_lib\app\deploy_util.py", line 395, in Deploy
        extra_config_settings)
      File "C:\Users\sudha\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\api_lib\app\appengine_api_client.py", line 188, in DeployService
        message=message)
      File "C:\Users\sudha\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\api_lib\app\operations_util.py", line 244, in WaitForOperation
        sleep_ms=retry_interval)
      File "C:\Users\sudha\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\api_lib\util\waiter.py", line 266, in WaitFor
        sleep_ms=sleep_ms)
      File "C:\Users\sudha\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\core\util\retry.py", line 222, in RetryOnResult
        if not should_retry(result, state):
      File "C:\Users\sudha\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\api_lib\util\waiter.py", line 260, in _IsNotDone
        return not poller.IsDone(operation)
      File "C:\Users\sudha\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\api_lib\app\operations_util.py", line 169, in IsDone
        encoding.MessageToPyValue(operation.error)))
    OperationError: Error Response: [13] An internal error occurred while creating a Google Cloud Storage bucket.
    ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] An internal error occurred while creating a Google Cloud Storage bucket.

    C:\Users\sudha\Desktop\nodejs-docs-samples\appengine\hello-world>
```

Comment: First, check your [IAM & admin Service accounts](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts). Tell me if you have the **App Engine app default service account** and the **Compute Engine default service account**. Note the email addresses used for each account (as **Service account ID**). These accounts _allow the machines_ in your project to handle resources from your project (like a bucket). Then, switch to [IAM & admin IAM](https://pantheon.corp.google.com/iam-admin/iam/) and check if those emails are members of your IAM, and what are their roles. I'll wait for your feedback.

Comment: Yes I have App Engine app default service account and the Compute Engine default service account.

Comment: OK, now check [IAM](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam/) and let me know if those mails are listed as members there and, also, what roles do they have.

Comment: Will it compromise security to add screenshot of both IAM and service accounts ?? IF not then I can add screenshots and it would be easy for you to check ?? Also thanks for helping me here.

Comment: For Service account `App Engine app default service account` it has `Role` as `Editor`, and for Service account `Compute Engine default service account` it also has `Role` as `Editor`.

Comment: Do you also have an account with `Cloud Container Builder` and an `App Engine flexible environment Service Agent`? If there are no other accounts added by you, you should have around 8 service accounts with various roles, automatically created, and your owner account. Those service accounts have various permissions over App Engine, Compute Engine, Container Engine and Cloud Storage, as all these products are used when deploying in App Engine.

Comment: There are 9 accounts can i add screenshot of all of it ??

Comment: Also there are 2 Service accounts which I have mentioned in previous comments. It would be better if I can add the image ??

Comment: Yes I have two separate accounts for both `Cloud Container Builder` and `App Engine flexible environment Service Agent`

Comment: @Tudormi I have added pics for both Service accounts and roles please have a relook at my post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159595/discussion-between-tudormi-and-sudhanshu-gaur).

Comment: This issue is currently being investigated: [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/69192294) and [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/69623842)

Answer (score 10):

Try by setting this configuration parameter first:

`gcloud config set app/use_deprecated_preparation True`

as proposed in [Google's Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/69192294)

Comment: Actually I already got the solution, it was happening because the debit card which I added was not perfectly linked when I added some other card the problem was resolved. I think there is some bug in their functioning. Thanks for help anyways :)

Comment: Hello Tudormi, can you please have a look at my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47486110/do-i-need-to-setup-a-reverse-proxy-behind-google-app-engine-or-not maybe you can help.

Comment: @SudhanshuGaur Hi! I appreciate for calling me out. Unfortunately I won't be able to help before Monday, but expect a response from me then.

Comment: Not a problem, Thanks.

Comment: @Tudormi I am getting an issue in Google Cloud Logging, can you please help me **SO link** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52065164/google-app-engine-why-some-logs-are-not-getting-shown?noredirect=1#comment91140389_52065164  **google Issue tracker link** is https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/113560166

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the configuration parameter with:

```
gcloud config set app/stop_previous_version true
```