# Do I need to Setup a Reverse Proxy behind Google App Engine or not?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, reverse-proxy

I am running my app on `Google App engine` and I have linked my `domain` which I bought from GoDaddy to the app engine along with the `SSL` which I have also bought from GoDaddy.

I read it on many sites that running server on `port 80` without `Reverse Proxy` can cause you major security issues. But I can't see which of these issues are they talking about. Also as I am running my app on `port 5555` I even tried to ping my domain and the IP was `216.239.XX.21` where X possible values can be `(32, 34, 36 and 38)` which is same for all other `App Engine` server. So I think that as if any `hacker/malicious` user tries to do something malicious to my app then in order to do that he/she have to know my IP which `App Engine` is hiding by default.

So, I want to know as `App Engine` is already **hiding my IP** so do I have to use any `Reverse Proxy Server` like `Nginx` on my `App Engine` or not ??

Also if I need to use `Reverse Proxy` then I saw these two posts [nginx-as-reverse-proxy-for-google-app-engine-application](https://serverfault.com/questions/275310/nginx-as-reverse-proxy-for-google-app-engine-application) 
and [using-nginx-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-speedy-app-engine-development/](http://desmondbrand.com/blog/2011/12/05/using-nginx-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-speedy-app-engine-development/).

Where in First Post it is `not` recommended to use `Reverse Proxy` whereas in Second Post it is recommended to use `Reverse Proxy`. That's why I am confused which would be a better approach.

Please Help Me Guys.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After posting this question on Google groups they told me that There is no need for setting up reverse-proxy for both Flexible and As well as Standard Environment.

> - App Engine instances in the Standard environment [1](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/70018870) do not have public static IP addresses, and are completely protected by the main
>     Google Front-end server. Requests to your application first hit the
>     Google Front-end, then the front-end performs the SSL security checks
>     according to your uploaded certificate [2], and then forwards the
>     request to your App Engine instances using their internal IPs.
>     Therefore no reverse-proxy is required.
> - If you are using the App Engine Flexible environment [3], you are able to have static IPs for your instances as they use Compute Engine
>     VMs [4]. But, App Engine automatically loads Nginx proxy in front of
>     every App Engine Flexible instance pre-configured, so you do not have
>     to set this up at all. All you have to do is follow the guide to
>     uploading your SSL cert [5], and requests will be vetted by the Google
>     Front-end just like the Standard environment above. Therefore no added
>     reverse-proxy is required.

**Full answer can be found here** [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/70018870)

Comment: For some additional context, there's now [serverless NEGs](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/negs/serverless-neg-concepts) offered by GCP that will allow you to have a single IP and configure certs as you want, like any other HTTP(S) load balancer.